# LEFT OUTER JOIN IN ENTITY FRAMEWORK

Tags: entity-framework, linq, left-join

I am trying left outer join entity framework by joining 4 tables:

```
var ssss = (from supplier in entity.Supplier_master 
            join city in entity.City_master on supplier.Supplier_City equals city.id 
            join state in entity.State_master on supplier.Supplier_State equals state.id 
            join country in entity.Country_master on supplier.Supplier_Country equals country.id 
            where supplier.Supplier_Code.Equals(sup_code) 
            select (new { supplier.Supplier_Code, supplier.Supplier_Name, city.City_Name, state.State_Name, country.Country_Name, supplier.Supplier_TradeMark })).ToList();
```

The above code is executed as inner join, please help me to find the solution to done left outer join.

Comment: The joins in EF are best to be performed by EF itself. You should really define and use navigation properties.

Comment: Please edt your question to (a) rewrite the title so it is not all-caps shouting; (b) trim the txtspk from the body, and make a mental note that this is not a chatroom; (c) show `CREATE TABLE` statements for each of your tables. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Join the 2 table usering "into alias" then select from that result.

Example:

```
var query = from supplier in entity.Supplier_master
            join city in entity.City_master on supplier.Supplier_City equals city.id  into citySupplier
            from cs in citySupplier.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new { your fields) };
```

Comment: There is no need to change the range variable name (`city` -> `cs`). It's better to keep the same name `city` so the rest of the query is the same as with inner join.